# USB-C to laptop charger?

Tags: laptop, power, usb-c

I have an ASUS laptop. The charger tip looks like these ones:

[image: charger tip]

I find my 120W, 1kg charger too bulky. As GaN tech is getting more popular, I prefer a USB-C charger like those from RavPower and Anker. However, I cannot find a USB-C to laptop charger cord to use it, regardless of laptop brand. 100W limit is not a problem, I rarely use my laptop at 100% of both CPU and GPU.

From my understanding, the USB PD needs some information about power requirements, and this information must be exchanged digitally. Old-style chargers don't seem to work that way.

Can such type of cable exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is yes it could exist, but likely does not.

A USB-C Power Delivery Source communicates with the “Sink” over the configuration data line which is provided in a USB-C connector. This data line is what allows devices to request different voltages such as 5, 12, or 20 volts. The standard power port on an ASUS appears to be power and ground only, meaning it doesn’t have the data line to be able to communicate the required voltage. However, you can buy boards similar to Arduinos which can act as this interface and allow you to toggle between a few preset voltage levels from a standard USB-C connector. The output from that could then be used to power the laptop. I don’t know if any manufacturers make premade adapters, as the market for them is likely small; however, it is possible to make your own if you have the supplies and knowledge on how to do it.

Comment: They do exist and Lenovo makes them for their hardware.  This works by having an active cable that does the power negotiation on the behalf of the computer or other device.  This also "works" because Lenovo has a big enough market that making such cables is good business.

Answer (score 1):

I did a search for USB C pd to 20V cable and found at least one item on eBay called "Usb 3.1 Type C Usb-C Dc 20V 4.0 1.7Mm Power Plug Pd Emulator Trigger Charge 2M4" This appears to do exactly what I would expect that is tell the USB C cable connection it want 20V and then just pass the two pins out. So my answer is yes it exists.

I have received one of these in the mail - It has a molded plug with "For DELL" on it and I can report my Dell laptop charges, it  does not give the unrecognized power supply it runs off my USB C -PD mains power supply and my USB-C PD Car adapter power supply (60W USB C PD output)

I cannot find the listing on Ebay for this anymore

I did find some "decoy" chips which support 12V from USB-C PD - using jumpers
[image]  and I also found the  ZY12PDN [link to description](http://budgetlightforum.com/node/69061)- which outputs 5A at selectable 5V, 9V, 12V, 15V or 20V.

So the chips exist,and so you should be able find a consumable plug device and get 12V out of at a maximum of 5A for 60W.  I can't anymore not even the ones I bought - just hobyist type gear

Comment: I also like small supplies and I found some UsbC to plug tips as well for less that $4 , I'm so glad you asked this question they all do seem to be 18 to 20V but my laptop's are all dell so I think that's ok

Comment: What do you think about the quality?

Comment: I finally found this one. Underpowered, but yeah it works (as per the ads... :D) http://www.powerfalcon.net/cn/web/productinfo.php?id=10055